# Problem Rendering

Tags: rendering

I feel rater stupid asking this, But I somehow destroyed my project. So I made some complex models, added textures, animations etc. And when I click render, nothing happens. I have rendered many things before and a new project works just fine. Since I don't want to restart and export everything, I'd like to try to fix my project. I deleted anything unnecessary and made a [test.blend](https://drive.google.com/open?id=16KM8M8TrzFRLey_B4n26D8N6m18Dnk3Y) file to try to troubleshoot. I looked into other rendering problems, but my problem seems to be different.
Maybe you can help me figure out whats wrong here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add some screenshots and your project .blend file.

Comment: Note that including a file normally doesn't mean you are free from including screenshots. Not everyone is able to download file just to see what the problem is while screenshots themselves can help to define the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some picture in your Video Sequence Editor and Sequencer enabled in your render settings:

[image]

So Blender tries to render that instead of the scene. You can disable the Sequencer in the render settings, or you can delete the image in it and leave it empty if you wish to render the scene.

Comment: Thanks a Lot! That did it!

Answer (score -1):

The light in your scene is pointing away from the object

[image]

Comment: That's a Sun Lamp. The line only shows its direction. That is not a problem at all. The light strength is set to a high value, but it works fine. I would suggest testing the solution before posting it.